# Modifying svg attributes with javascript has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to modify an svg tag with javascript to make it resizable, but my changes have no effect. The reason that I need to do this is that this tag is rendered by a library that I can't modify, and thus it seems like my only choice is to modify the svg with javascript.

I know that the tag that this script produces is correct since I am able to copy the tag to a new html document and it will work (I have included it in the sample code), so it seems like I need some way to force the svg to recognize that it has been changed (or another way to modify the svg).

Here's a HTML page that shows my problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var svg = $('#testsvg').find('svg')[0];

            var w = svg.getAttribute('width').replace('px', '');
            var h = svg.getAttribute('height').replace('px', '');

            svg.removeAttribute('width');
            svg.removeAttribute('height');

            svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h);
            svg.setAttribute('preserveaspectratio', 'xminymin meet')

            $(svg)
                .css('width', '100%')
                .css('height', '100%')
                .css('background-color', 'white');
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #333;">
        <div style="width: 80%; height: 40%;">
            <svg id="resultsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white; " viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveaspectratio="xminymin meet">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"></circle>
            </svg>
         </div>
        <div id="testsvg" style="width: 80%; height: 40%;">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100px" height="100px">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
            </svg>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive so

```
svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h);
svg.setAttribute('preserveaspectratio', 'xminymin meet')
```

should be written

```
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h);
svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
```

width and height on the `<svg>` element are attributes and not styles (unlike html) so you should use `setAttribute('width', '100%')` rather than `.css('width', '100%')`

Comment: for fellow googlers : also note the `[0]` after the `find('svg')` to get the DOM element from the jQuery element. This is important to enable the use of `setAttribute()`. the jQuery `attr()` method cannot be used because the SVG DOM is different from the HTML DOM (cf. http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#dom)

Comment: This is only true if they are not using JQuery SVG(possibly).

It says right in the link.

The SVG DOM is different to the HTML DOM for which jQuery was designed. Thus, jQuery's functions that work with classes don't work on SVG nodes.

To overcome this problem you can use the jQuery SVG DOM extension. Add the extension in the head section of your page.


I don't see why this couldn't be used for any SVG issue, but it might be too embedded with JquerySVG, but who knows what a little editing would do :)

Answer (score 7):

`jQuery` convert attribute name to lower case; e.g., instead of setting a `viewBox` attribute, it will set `viewbox`. Unfortunately, SVG (a XML dialect) element attribute names are case sensitive.

If you wanted to use jQuery consistently, you could use `$.attrHooks` to handle the case sensitive attributes:

```
['preserveAspectRatio', 'viewBox'].forEach(function(k) {
  // jQuery converts the attribute name to lowercase before
  // looking for the hook. 
  $.attrHooks[k.toLowerCase()] = {
    set: function(el, value) {
      if (value) {
        el.setAttribute(k, value);
      } else {
        el.removeAttribute(k, value);
      }
      return true;
    },
    get: function(el) {
      return el.getAttribute(k);
    },
  };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var svg = $('#testsvg');
  var w = svg.attr('width').replace('px', '');
  var h = svg.attr('height').replace('px', '');

  svg.attr({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    viewBox: [0, 0, w, h].join(' '),
    preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid meet'
  })
});
```

Note that `el.attr('viewBox', null)` would failed; your hook setter won't be called. Instead you should use `el.removeAttr('viewBox')` or `el.attr('viewBox', false)`.

For other attribute like stroke, I would put them in a stylesheet.

```
svg {
  background-color: white;
}
circle {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

If you need to add/toggle class to change the style of a specific elements, you need to use jQuery 1.12+ or jquery 2.2+.